# How to add ALPN to Java 7

Tags: java, undertow, alpn

Is possible to add ALPN to the boot class path in a Java 7 application? If yes, how can we do it?

There're many samples on Internet telling how to do it via Java 8 and Undertow, Tomcat, Jetty, etc..

Do I need to add a security library into my VM? It seems Java 8 already includes them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add ALPN to Java 7. Follow the same instructions as you would for Java 8:

1. Download ALPN boot
2. Add the following JVM flag: -Xbootclasspath/p:path_to_alpn_boot_jar

Just make certain to use the correct version of alpn-boot for your JVM version. See the table here for version compat: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions